# Compiling dvb-apps tarball into Solaris 10 SPARC

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, solaris, dvb

I have Solaris 10 SPARC edition installed onto a Oracle/Sun SPARC server. I wish to install dvb-apps tarball using my gcc compiled installed into Solaris 10 (gcc-9.1.0 compiled and installed from source files packaged into official gcc-9.1.0 tarball archive)
I can configure the archive successfully via the './configure' command. BUt when I try and compile the archive via the 'make' command the gc compiler enters the ./lib/libdvbapi/ and attempts to compile the first file in directory which is 'dvbaudio.c'
Inside the dvbaudio.c file there is a paragraph declaring files to include as follows...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/dvb/audio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "dvbaudio.h"
```

I know that the following 3 files can be found in /usr/include directory within my Solaris 10 SPARC OS

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

However the next 3 files do not appear within Solaris 10 /usr/include. they are found within linux/ubuntu instead

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/dvb/audio.h>
```

Can I simply transfer these files into the /lib/libdvbapi directory and edit the relevant '#include ' statements to reflect the designated files new location. Or is it harder and complicated than this. If this process cannot be done. Is there an archive of dvb-apps that is Solaris SPARC compatible??

I shall await your answer in due time. Thanks for any help you can give me

Regards

Comment: Most likely no, you cannot. "Linux" makes it very clear that the functions these headers refer to only exist on Linux. Porting this code to Solaris will require some development work. Looks like [DVB apps are specific to Linux API](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/legacy/dvbapi/ch01s04.html).